# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file CheckBox

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-drawable

I have published an application and I see that some users keep getting errors when they are in the sign-up activity.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.yyy/com.xxx.yyy.SignUpActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #137 in com.xxx.yyy:layout/activity_sign_up: Binary XML file line #137 in com.xxx.yyy:layout/activity_sign_up: Error inflating class CheckBox
```

When I go to `layout/activity_sign_up` to line 137 I got this:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_showPass"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cb_visible_styles"
    android:button="@null"
    android:scaleX="0.6"
    android:scaleY="0.6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/et_SignUpPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/et_SignUpPassword"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/et_SignUpPassword" />
```

Which is used to show the eye in the EditText:

[image]

The `drawable/cb_visible_styles` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_show" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_hide" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_show" />
</selector>
```

Where cb_show/cb_hide are png files:

[image]

I can't figure out what causes the error.
Some places say it is because of Scaling, some say it is because of Density, Can't figure out why for many users it is fine but for a specific few it doesn't.

One time it appeared on Samsung S21, the other at Nexus 5X. One time on Android 10 and the other on Android 8.1.

Thank you

Comment: I've tested your example and I don't have a crash at all.

Comment: Try to add a version of this png into `drawable-nodpi` and see.. Please let me know I am curious to know the reason

Comment: @HenryTwist, I also dont get any crashes when I test it. Yet, I get it in my crashlyitics logs.

Comment: Have you tested it with a device at every density level?

Comment: @HenryTwist, Tried to test it on different density devices in Firebase's Test lab, I can't say if I checked all. The device that made that error is Samsung Galaxy A21s which falls somewhere in those densities from my understanding.

Comment: which support lib version are you using? there is a bug in support library 23.2 which causes checkbox to crash

Comment: I use this one if its what you meant: 'com.android.support:design:30.0.0'

Answer (score 2):

I think you do a lot of hassle google provides an easy way to apply show hide password check XML below

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/passwordLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            app:endIconTint="@color/edit_text_icon_gray"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:errorTextColor="@color/error_color"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/white"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24"
            app:startIconTint="@color/edit_text_icon_gray"
            fancy:endIconMode="password_toggle">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/regular_font"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:theme="@style/MyEditTextStyle2" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: it is indeed a good solution but I have my reasons to stick with the EditText + Checkbox tho =]

Answer (score 0):

Remove **Third Item** tag from **drawable/cb_visible_styles.** and try to run.

**Before:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_show" android:state_checked="false" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_hide" android:state_checked="true" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_show" />
   </selector>
```

**After:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_show" android:state_checked="false" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_hide" android:state_checked="true" />
   </selector>
```